# Fallout 4, tag for research, items appearing green

Tags: fallout-4

I've been playing Fallout 4 a lot since the day of release, I have been having no issues and have been going through the game fine, until today.

I think I did something to make all the items I had tagged for research to be highlighted in green. I would like to change it back to just the magnifying glass but I don't know how.

I'm playing on PC, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Highlighted in green? Sounds like the upgraded Scrapper perk.

Comment: Yeah I did just get that, thanks a lot, by any chance is there a a way to turn it off but still be able to scrap the other parts? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

The highlighting is part of the Scrapper perk, so there is no way to get rid of it once you have the perk. All it does is highlight items so you aren't losing out on anything.

From your comment it seems you are confused about it's functionality. Highlighting a certain resource like leather or copper won't stop you from getting other components when breaking down an item. Say you highlighted leather, a teddy bear breaks down into leather and 3 cloth everytime you destroy one. Highlighting one component doesn't stop you from collecting the other ones.

Comment: @Wilf You should mark this as the accepted answer so that VanBuzzKill can get those sweet sweet points.

Answer (score 0):

I think it only highlights items you have tagged for search. Only items with favorited components are highlighted. If you unfavorite them nothing should be green.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This is true, but I'm not sure how much it's adding to the existing answer. Especially because this fact is acknowledged in the question: "I did something to make all the items I had tagged for research to be highlighted in green"

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to go to your junk menu and select show components then select research on all items with the magnifying glass. you may need to do this a few times as you find all the components you marked but eventually, it will be back to normal, and of course, you can reselect as needed.